# How to encode HD video to smallest size but maintaining its best quality?

Tags: video, encode, video-encoding

I have searched a lot about this issue and I have to admit that I am a newbie in this particular encoding stuff. Most of the information I get from the webs does not provide me a comprehensive answer regarding what I addressed here. I know that it's impossible to compress the video to a very small size but maintaining its original high definition.

What I would like to know is like for a 1080p 1GB movie, how can I encode it into about 100MB size but the quality will be in least influenced. I saw many websites provide this kind of encoded video but I really got no idea how they done it. Does it requires a high skill in encoding or just the aid of some software?

Hope to get some ideas from you guys and it would be the best if someone could possibly teach me to do this. Thank you very much in advanced for all the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When encoding video, the filesize does not only rely on video quality but also on the amount of included subtitles, (when not hardcoded) sound quality, sound sources (a video can have multiple languages included for example) and various other things.

What you could do is strip a video of superflous material, which should give you a good start. You could get rid of all subtitles you don't want, only leave one soundstream, lower the sound quality from 5.1 to stereo, from FLAC to 192kb/s, just a few examples of what is possible.

As far as I know this is done with the help of various programs. I do not know any right off the bat, as I never really bother with encoding/decoding, but this should help you on your way. Do remember that the most effective way of limiting filesize in video is, unfortunately, lowering video quality.